# asp.net login layout and positioning

Tags: asp.net

I'm using asp.net's login control; two textboxes with the labels on the left and a button beneath (the control renders as a table with 3 rows). When the user enters an incorrect login, the page is posted back and the failure text "incorrect login" is displayed by adding a row between the password textbox and the button.

The problem is that when the failure text is displayed, the new row that's inserted shifts the button down slightly.

It looks odd and off. How can I rearrange this so that when the failure text appears it doesn't shift the login button.

Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: Without example code it is difficult to answer this question.  How is your layout/markup setup? <div>? <table>? Does the problem have to do with the login button alone or do the text boxes play a role in the button shifting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, if anyone gets to this page because of a layout problem with the login control, it's actually pretty easy to solve. By default, the control renders as a table and there's nothing you can do to change the layout of the default control because you don't have access to the HTML.

You need to switch the page to design mode and on the control, click "Convert to Template". When you go back to the source page, the HTML becomes accessible and you can see the HTML of the table that contains the various asp controls. Yank the table and put the control inside divs that you control!

Answer (score 0):

Check out the documentation for the [Login control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.login%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

Assuming there isn't CSS or markup on the page causing the shifting, you should be able to control the style of the failure text via [`FailureTextStyle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.login.failuretextstyle%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) property.